# htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

www.source.com should be redirected to www.destination.com

but www.source.com/mypage.html should not be redirect, it should still navigate to www.source.com/mypage.html

I tried this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) www.destination.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

when I accessed www.source.com/mypage.html, it displays page not found as there is no page www.destination.com/mypage.html.

How can I achieve this redirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?source\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.destination.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: source.com, www.source.com, [http://www.source.com](http://www.source.com) all should be redirected. How to achieve this?

Comment: Check out my updated answer.